# ¿Como puedo relacionar una clase llamada Registro con una clase llamada Parkig?

Tags: java

Como ya he mencionado soy nuevo en la programación.

Trabando en el mismo proyecto ya reseñado del Parking se me presenta el problema de crear una clase "Registro" cuya función básicamente es tener métodos que permitan registrar el horario de entrada y salida de los coches, para luego aplicar la tarifa correspondiente. El detalle es que solo se puede registrar la entrada de un coche partiendo de 2 supuestos: 1-Debe estar dado de alta (Esto ya lo solucione con ayuda de algunos colegas de esta plataforma) y 2-No puedo registrar una entrada de coche que ya esta en el parking.

Para ser sincero el problema se me presenta desde el mismo planteamiento de los métodos, no tengo claridad de que atributos crear sobre la clase "Registro" ni tampoco como logro que, solo pidiendo la matricula en la clase AppParking, pueda hacer que el sistema verifique que la misma ya previamente ha sido dada de alta en la clase "Parking" y por ende corrobore que es posible darle entrada a dicho coche, esto ultimo se debe plantear en la clase "Registro".

Perdonad si es muy complicado lo que planteo, creo que solo necesito un pequeño empujón que me permita saber como empezar.

Os dejo todas las clases hechas hasta ahora.
Nota: Cambiare la tabla Hash por una HashMap.

Gracias de antemano.

```
**Clase Usuario**
@author JOELS
 */
public class Usuario {
    private String nombre;
    private String telefono;
    private String matricula;

    public Usuario(){    
    }


    public Usuario(String nombre, String telefono, String matricula){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.matricula=matricula;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuarios{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", telefono=" + telefono + ", matricula=" + matricula + '}';
    }
```

**Clase Parking**

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author JOELS
 */
public class Parking {

    //Como Atributo creamos una Lista que luego sera definida como Hashtable
    private Hashtable<String,Usuario> usuarios;

    //Constructor
    public Parking(){
        this.usuarios= new Hashtable<String,Usuario>();

    }

    //Creo metodo para dar de alta
    public void alta(Usuario usuario){
        this.usuarios.put(usuario.getMatricula(), usuario);
    }

    //Metodo para dar de baja a partir de la key
    public String baja(String  b){
        if(this.usuarios.containsKey(b) && this.usuarios!=null){
           this.usuarios.remove(b);
           System.out.println("Vehiculo dado de baja satisfactoriamente");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Matricula no encontada");
        }
        return null;

        }
}


**Clase Registro**  **(Aquí es donde no tengo ni idea de como empezar, coloco lo hecho)**

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Hashtable;

/**
 *
 * @author JOELS
 */
public class Registro {

    private Hashtable<String,Parking> registros;

    public Registro(){
        this.registros= new Hashtable<String,Parking>();
    }

    public String entrada(String a, Parking parking){
        this.registros.put(a,parking);


    }
```

**Clase AppParking**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author JOELS
 */
public class AppParking {
public static void main (String[] args){

Parking parking = new Parking();

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int opcion=0; 

do{
System.out.println("Bienvenido al Parking Prosperidad-Indique la opcion deseada");
System.out.println("1-Dar de alta a usuario");
System.out.println("2-Dar de baja a usuario");
System.out.println("3-Registrar entrada");
System.out.println("4-Registrar salida");
System.out.println("5-Mostrar vehiculos");
System.out.println("0-Salir del sistema");
opcion=teclado.nextInt();
teclado.nextLine();

Usuario u = null;

switch(opcion){
    case 1: //Dar de alta a usuario
    System.out.println("Nombre: ");
    String nombre=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Telefono: ");
    String telefono=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Matricula: ");
    String matricula=teclado.nextLine();


    //Preguntar si los datos son correctos
    System.out.println("¿Son correctos los datos? Nombre: "+nombre+ " Telefono: "+telefono+" Matricula: "+matricula);
    System.out.println("Pulse 1 si es correcto / Pulse 2 si es incorrecto");
    int pulsar=teclado.nextInt();
    switch(pulsar){
        case 1:
         u= new Usuario(nombre,telefono,matricula);
         parking.alta(u);
         System.out.println("Los datos se han guardado satisfactoriamente");
         break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Vaya a menu principal y repita la carga de datos");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Volviendo a menu principal");
    }
        break;


    case 2: //Dar de baja a usuario
        System.out.println("Indique matricula del vehiculo a dar de baja:");
        String b=teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("¿Desea dar de baja Matricula: "+b+" ?  Pulse 1 para Si / Pulse 2 para No");
        int pulsarMatricula=teclado.nextInt();
        switch(pulsarMatricula){
            case 1:
                parking.baja(b);


                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Baja cancelada / Volviendo a menu principal");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Volviendo a menu principal");

        }



    break;

    case 3: //Registrar entrada
        System.out.println("**Nueva Entrada**");
        System.out.println("Indique Matricula");
        String c=teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("¿Desea dar entrada a la Matricula: "+c+" ?  Pulse 1 para Si / Pulse 2 para No");
        int darEntrada=teclado.nextInt();
        switch (darEntrada){
            case 1:

            break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Entrada cancelada / Volviendo a menu principal");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Volviendo a menu principal");
        }


        break;

    case 4: //Registar salida

        break;

    case 5:


    default:
        System.out.println("Saliendo");

}
}while(opcion!=0);


}    
}
```

Comment: Recueda aceptar las respuestas que fueron correctas en las preguntas.. Probablemente tu problema aqui sea simple, pero vas a tener que bajar el problema a su minima expresion, asi como esta es muy dificil ayudarte y tratar de seguir todo tu codigo.